# How to sort OrderedDict when keys contains strings and numbers - Python

Tags: python

I am using `OrderedDict` to sort a `dict` whose keys contain both strings and numbers. Here is my code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
x = {}
x['mon'] = 10
x['day_1'] = 1
x['day_2'] = 2
x['day_10'] = 10
x['day_11'] = 11
dictionary1 = OrderedDict(sorted(x.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[0])))
dictionary2 = OrderedDict(sorted(x.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

I would like the output looks like (I do not care the location of `mon:2`):

```
OrderedDict([('mon', 2), ('day_1', 1), ('day_2', 2), ('day_10', 10), ('day_11', 11)])
```

but neither of the method worked. So I guess I might need to customize a sorting rule? Any suggestions?

### update:

Here is my combined answer (Simeon Visser and hcwhsa):

```
def convert_dict_key(key):
    try:
        return int(key.split('_')[1])
    except:
        return key

alphanum_key = lambda (key, value): convert_dict_key(key)
dictionary = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=alphanum_key)
```

Comment: This is called a 'natural sort'

Comment: Dup: [Does Python have a built in function for string **natural sort**?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Comment: @hcwhsa: Sort of. But that post does not have the solution using `OrderDict`

Comment: @tao.hong You're sorting a list here(`x.items()`) not `OrderedDict`.

Comment: @Thanks for pointing that out. I do get an idea from that post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> dictionary3 = OrderedDict(sorted(x.items(), key=lambda (key, value): int(key.split('_')[1])))
>>> dictionary3
OrderedDict([('day_1', 1), ('day_2', 2), ('day_10', 10), ('day_11', 11)])
```

This splits the keys by `'_'` and sorts the day numbers as integers.